# Was there a real life inspiration behind the Duke brothers in Trading Places?

Tags: trading-places

The Duke brothers in [Trading Places](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086465/) remind me of the Koch brothers, and based on [a quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=trading%20places%20koch%20brothers&oq=trading) I'm definitely not alone. Is there any evidence that the characters in the film were at least inspired by real people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The orange juice trading scheme was likely based on an attempt to [corner the silver market](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086465/trivia?item=tr0685681) by the Hunt Brothers....

> The story about the Dukes' cornering of the orange juice market was
>   probably inspired by the ["Silver Thursday" market crash of March 27,
>   1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Thursday), when the Hunt brothers of Texas tried to corner the silver
>   market and subsequently failed to meet a one hundred million dollar
>   margin call.

The characters themselves were supposedly inspired by [two brothers who were doctors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086465/trivia?item=tr0660285).

> The idea for the film was inspired by a tennis game. "There were these
>   two brothers who were both doctors who I would play tennis with on a
>   fairly regular basis, and they were incredibly irritating to play with
>   because they had a major sibling rivalry going, all the time about
>   everything," Screenwriter Timothy Harris explained. He presented the
>   idea of brothers arguing the "nature versus nurture" debate to his
>   writing partner, Herschel Weingrod, and the two went to work.